# How to find the number of homomorphisms between two general groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Given two groups of the same order $G_1$ and $G_2$, how do I find the number of homomorphisms between these two groups?

Is it possible for any groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ of the same order or only for some specific type of groups like cyclic groups?

In my specific case, $G_1$ is $S_5$ and $G_2$ is $D_{120}$ but I would like to know how to solve this kind of questions for general groups, if possible.

EDIT: I'm not looking for anything more advanced than an introductory course on group theory

Comment: It's quite hard.  The best known general results are when both groups are f.g. abelian.

Comment: Whats always a good start is to look at the possible kernels of morphisms i.e. the normal subgroups of $G_1$. In the case of $S_5$ this gives a fairly good upper bound for consideration. As has been noted, in general that's not easy.